# How to URL redirect/rewrite using the .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to write .htaccess rewriterule for the below URL.
I am new to htaccess.

http://velloredentists.com/search.php?s=VASAN+DENTAL+CLINIC&c=Bagayam )

to

http://velloredentists.com/search/VASAN+DENTAL+CLINIC/Bagayam

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Google .htaccess and give it a try yourself, SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Have you tried google or you know how to search \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked on my apache server :

```
RewriteEngine On
#Redirect "/search.php?s=foo&c=bar to 
#/search/foo/bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search.php\?s=([^&]+)&c=([^\s]+) [NC] 

#Rewrite "/search/foo/bar" to
#"/search.php?s=foo&c=bar"
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?s=$1&c=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - First you need to check if the file `.htaccess` exists in the root of your website.

2 - If the file `.htaccess` exists, download it from your site, add the lines below to the end of the file, and upload the modified file back to your site. Please make a copy of the original file `.htaccess`. So if anything goes wrong, you may restore the original file.

3 - If the file `.htaccess` does not exist, create a new file `.htaccess` and add the lines below to it. Then upload it to the root of your website. You may delete it if anything goes wrong.

Add the following lines to `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /search.php?s=$1&c=$2 [L]
```